# Firebase returns wrong query result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a React app with Firebase as its backend. I am fetching some chat data from firestore, and I do this inside a useEffect with `activeChat` as a dependency. This `activeChat` basically holds some information such as *combinedId* (which I use to uniquely identify a chat)

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let ref = null;
  if (activeChat) {
    ref = collection(db, `directMessages/${activeChat.combinedId}/chats`)
  }

  let unsub = undefined;
  if (ref) {
    const q = query(ref, orderBy("createdAt"), limitToLast(6));
    unsub = onSnapshot(q, (snap) => {
      console.log("*****************")
      console.log("size =>", snap.docs.length)
      snap.docs.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.data()))
    })
  }
  return () => {
    unsub && unsub();
  }
}, [activeChat])
```

The above code produces the following output:

[image: console output]

I can see that the useEffect ran twice, I think that is because my React app is running in `<React.StrictMode>`.

- But regardless the result should have been same both times, because data has not changed.
- Also if instead of `onSnapshot` I use `getDocs`, useEffect only runs once and I get correct length result (which is 6).

Why is this happenning? Please help me identify the problem, any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Do you have (or did you ever have) caching enabled on the device where you run this code? If so, that first result with `onSnapshot` is coming from the cache, while the second result is coming from the server.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen for replying. I tried - `if (!querySnapshot.metadata.fromCache)`  and it worked. BUT this is strange because I opened a fresh browser window in incognito mode, so how did that the 1 doc end up in cache? ALSO inside afromentioned if condition I tried `querySnapshot.docChanges(changeDoc => {})` and then console logged docs which satisfied `changeDoc.type === "added"` and it only printed 5 documents, when it should have printed that last (6th) document as well. I really do not understand this behaviour, please be kind enough to help me out.

Comment: Despite what its name suggests, the `fromCache` flag doesn't actually mean that the data came from the cache, but rather that it may not reflect the current value from the server. Not sure if that explains what you have, but it was the first/only thing I could think of.